# Why Can't I break out of the loop?

Tags: python

Python beginner here. Sorry if it's a basic python concept

```
over = False

def run():
    user_input = input("Over? (y/n): ")
    if(user_input == 'y'):
        over = True

while not over:
    run()
```

Although the input is 'y' the loop doesn't stop.

Comment: Please read python scoping rules here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `global over`, so function `run()` will change global variable

```
over = False

def run():
    global over
    user_input = input("Over? (y/n): ")
    if(user_input == 'y'):
        over = True

while not over:
    run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using a global variable here. Return a boolean, and call `run` as the condition of the loop. (At this point, you may want to reconsider the name `run` as well.)

```
def run():
    user_input = input("Over? (y/n)")
    return user_input == 'y'

while run():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the *local* variable `over` inside the function `run()`, but you aren't passing it out to the scope from which it was called. Instead return the value to the calling scope like this:

```
over = False

def run():
    user_input = input("Over? (y/n): ")
    if(user_input == 'y'):
        over = True
    else:
        over = False
    return over

while not over:
    over = run()
```

Comment: You can (and should) remove the entire `if/else` clause and simply do `return user_input == 'y'`.